# Angular 6 not showing remote video stream WebRTC

Tags: asp.net, angular, webrtc, angular6

I'm implementing video conferencing using native WebRTC.

I have tried to implement video conferencing on plain javascript and it works well.
As signalling server I'm using ASP .NET Core with SignalR. Front-end part consists of Angular 6 with CLI.

On the first step I'm receiving my local video stream and attach it to video tag.

This is my ts file

```
    private getMedia(): void {

    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: true
      })
      .then((stream: MediaStream) => {
        this.localVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = stream;
        // this.localVideo.nativeElement.play();
        this.localStream = stream;

        this.callButton = false;

        this.pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection({
          iceServers: this.iceServers
        });

        this.pc1.onicecandidate = e => this.onIceCandidate(e);
        this.pc1.oniceconnectionstatechange = e => this.onIceStateChange(e);
        this.pc1.onaddstream = e => this.gotRemoteStream(e);

        this.pc1.addStream(stream);

      })
      .catch(e => alert(`getUserMedia() error: ${e.name}`));
  }
```

This is my component template:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h2 class="text-center">Invite to conversation</h2>
          <div class="form-group text-center">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly/>
            <button type="button" class="btn">Copy a link</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <video autoplay="autoplay" id="remoteVideo" #remoteVideo></video>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <button (click)="call()" type="button" class="btn btn-info" [disabled]="callButton">Call</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Answer</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Hangup</button>

      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <video autoplay="autoplay" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;" #localVideo></video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Then I have exchange with descriptors and candidates. Finally, I receive remote stream and attach it to srcObject property of video tag.

```
private gotRemoteStream(e: any): void {
    this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = e.stream;
    this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.play();
  }
```

gotRemoteStream is firing, but video is not showing.
Maybe somebody had the same problem? Many thanks!

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: @Chellappan no, everything is ok

Comment: so the problem is you are not able to stream the video on your video tag right?

Comment: @Chellappan you're right

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I missed step when moving code to Angular. I missed step of sending answer after setting remote descriptor. Double check all the steps :)

Comment: This is genius. Had exactly the same issue. Was getting a stream, active, but no video at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use SetAttribute to set width and height of video element

**Html**

```
 <div class="col-md-12">
      <video autoplay="autoplay" #localVideo></video>
    </div>
```

**ts**

Its becoz the new data still pushed into the element but it does not have reference try this to use ChangedDetectorRef

```
import {ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'video',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})


constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}




 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true}).
                then((stream)=>{
                  this.localVideo.nativeElement.setAttribute('width',500);
                  this.localVideo.nativeElement.setAttribute('height',500);
                  this.localVideo.nativeElement.srcObject=stream;
                  // this.localVideo.nativeElement.play();

                }).
                catch((e)=>console.error(e))


private gotRemoteStream(e: any): void {
    this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.srcObject = e.stream;
    this.cd.detectChanges();
    this.remoteVideo.nativeElement.play();
  }
```

Comment: Local video is working correctly. I have a problem with viewing of remote stream.

Comment: are you getting remote stream of data ?

Comment: yes, function gotRemoteStream  is firing, and I receive stream. I attach this stream to srcObject property, but remote stream still not shown.